# Facebook Login button for login in android app

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I've created a Facebook login Button in my application. This is my Java code, my activity extends `FacebookActivity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
                loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new  LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                LoginActivity.this.user = user;

            }
        });
}
```

With this code I'm getting the facebook login. Now I want to start an activity after successful login. Also I want to store the login id entered by the user for login.

currently I'm trying to override onComplete method in my activity. Which is giving me error, `The method onComplete(Bundle) of type LoginActivity must override or implement a supertype method`. I'm using facebook-android-sdk-3.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your SDK to the final version of the Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android.

The FacebookActivity class has been removed, which makes it much easier for you to integrate the SDK into existing apps and codebases.

The download and full walkthrough of getting setup is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To store login id this is how i proceed:

```
//set userID at start if session is valid
if (Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()){
   try{
   JSONObject me = new JSONObject(Utility.mFacebook.request("me"));
   String loginId = me.getString("id");
}catch...
```

In Facebook examples https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ you have a Login button already made

Comment: thanks for the reply. What is `mFacebook` here? and what about calling an activity after successful login?

Comment: mFacebook is an instance of Facebook,it is all in the facebook "simple" example. It provides you listeners (**SampleAuthListener** which implements **AuthListener**). You can override the method **onAuthSucceed()** and call your activity there.